# Wrong day value given by SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, android, simpledateformat

I'm working on an android application , when i need to send my current date to the server , i get my actual date by `currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();` and i'm parsing it using **SimpleDateFormat** `"yyyy/MM/DD"` , but the value i got for day is very weird : 38

There is the code i'm using :

```
 currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
 SimpleDateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/DD");
 String formattedDate1 = df1.format(currentTime.getTime());
```

[image]

**NB** : The date value returned by `currentTime` is correct

**PS** : This code was working correctly last days !

Comment: [DD is not what you think it is](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). Use dd.

Comment: `Calendar` is a legacy technology that should not be used.  The `java.time` package is a far better selection of classes, and there are plenty of backports available for Android.

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The pattern matching for parsing dates is case sensitive. You need to be very careful when generating your parsing pattern and refer to [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

`DD`, all capital/uppercase letters, refers to the *current day in the year*. Today, 7 February, is the 38th day in the year (31 in January + 7 in February.)

`dd`, all lowercase letters, refers to the *current day in the month*. This would parse as 7 for 7 February.

The correct pattern you should be using, therefore, is: `yyyy/MM/dd`.

It was working recently, because it was previously January. For the month of January only, `dd` and `DD` will return the same value.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you want `d` not `DD`

`D` returns the current day in year (31 days in Jan + 7 in Feb, I'm assuming).

`d` returns current day in month.

sauce: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html